# GWT Asnyccall can not be executed

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, gwt-rpc

I have written a few Asynccall to run something in Server. They work fine. But some tasks need a long time to run. I want to know their status during the execution. Then I write the new Asynccall that sends query periodically to server to check the task's status. But for the Callback, I can get only the Failure Message. I have checked the log, this AsyncCallbak can not be executed. Can anyone give me some suggestion?

```
        private BackendRemoteServiceAsync service = GWT.create(BackendRemoteService.class);

        Timer timer = new Timer() {
    public void run() {
        try {
           ApplicationController controller = ApplicationController
                         .getInstance();
           BackendRequest request = new BackendRequest(
                Command.COMMAND_TASK_CHECKSTATUS,
                 controller.getSessionToken());
           request.setDomain(Domains.TASK);

          ...
                  service.callBackend(request, new AsyncCallback<BackendRequest>() {

            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                task.setStatus("check status failure");
            }

            public void onSuccess(BackendRequest result) {

                if (result.isValid()) {
                task.setStatus("check status Success");                                                             ...
                } else
                            ;
                }

            });
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Window.alert("IllegalArgumentException: "+ ex.getMessage());
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Window.alert(t.getMessage());
            } finally {

            }
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleRepeating(5000);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't be executed" ? Do you mean it's not executed even though you call it or that there is and error and a log message telling the call failed (if so, could you post the log message please) ?

Comment: I am sure, that callback is called in every 5sec. But i think, the callback isnt executed, because the first line of the callback is logger.info(...), but i get nothing from the log file.

Comment: But is the `onFailure` called? Since you mention *I can get only the Failure Message*, what did you mean by that? And are the arguments of `service.callBackend` as you mention in the example or did you simplified the call here?

Comment: Yes, the onFailure is called. When onFailure is called, Browser should throw a popup window with the message " call failure".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the bug. In my method I must send some objects to backend. These objects must implement Serializeable.

Comment: Ok, congratulations. The SerializationException should have appeared in the logs.